# PostgreSQL performing an OR merge of two similar tables

Tags: database, postgresql

Running PostgreSQL 9.4.1.

I have two tables in a database (*a* and *b*) that share exactly the same schema:

table *a*:

```
 year |  r001   |  r002   
------+---------+---------
    1 |         |     600
  730 |         |        
 1000 |         |        
 1400 |         |        
 1450 |         |        
 1500 |         | 1467.15
 1600 |         | 1589.29
```

table *b*:

```
 year |  r001   |  r002   
------+---------+---------
    1 |     425 |     450
 1000 |     425 |     425
 1500 |     707 |     875
 1550 |     800 |     900
 1600 |   837.2 | 975.625
```

I would like to merge these two tables together, giving priority to table *a* , but replacing any NULL values in table *a* with non-NULL values from table *b*, if they exist, e.g., the values in the row at year 1000.

Also, where either table *a* or table *b* has a unique year, for example, table *a* has a row for year 730 and table *b* has a row for 1550, I would like these to be inserted into the resulting merged table, even if it is populated by NULLs only.

Thanks in advance for any ideas you may have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for a full outer join:

```
select year, 
       coalesce(a.r001, b.r001) as r001,
       coalesce(a.r002, b.r002) as r002
from table_a a
  full outer join table_b b using (year)
order by year;
```

The join syntax `using (year)` results in a single year column that contains the year value from that table that has one.

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/be6b1/1